# Odoo: inherit website footer to wrap contents inside a div

Tags: xml, odoo

Basically, I want to know if there is a way to inherit website.footer_default to wrap part of the contents inside a div.

To give a short example, if the initial template looks like this:

```
<template name="website.footer_default">
    <div id="footer">
        <content>
    </div>
</template>
```

And I'd like to replace it with:

```
<template name="website.footer_default">
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="mynewdiv">
            <content>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to achieve that without having to copy/paste all the  inside an xpath?

I also tried to inherit this template the qweb way, but the code doesn't seem to get executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve this without having to rewrite everything, with one limitation: it only works on web templates.

The solution uses javascript (and the fact that Odoo website comes bundled with jquery) to wrap elements at runtime.

Here is how that looks codewise:

```
<template name="new_footer_default" inherit_id="website.footer_default">
    <div id="footer" position="before">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#footer>*').wrapAll('<div class='mynewdiv'/>');
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Odoo 11 you can do this:

```
<template name="new_footer_default" inherit_id="website.footer_default">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='footer']" position="replace">
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="mynewdiv">$0</div>
        </div>
    </xpath>    
</template>
```

$0 is the marker where the content of the replaced node is added. it has to be a used as a text node containing only $0 (no whitespaces or other text)

See https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/views.html (search for replace)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Access the parent which contains the footer and replace it with your code wrapping the original code.

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="new_footer" inherit_id="website.layout">

            <xpath expr="//footer" position="replace">
                <footer>
                    <div class="mynewdiv">
                        <div id="footer_container">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </xpath>

        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that would require to rewrite all the code inside the div, which is precisely what I want to avoid.  Copy/pasting all the old content would require making a version of the module for each version of the website's addon that has a different footer. My boss does not accept that.